# Print specific data out of string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am running a command which returns data out of which I want just one part printed.

I have tried to sed but wasn't able to find the correct regex. The line my command is returning is as follows.

```
| |   |         |   "Device Characteristics" = {"Serial Number"="C08815303G7XXXXXX","Medium Type"="Solid State","Product Name"="APPLE SSD AP0512J","Vendor Name"="","Product Revision Level"="16.14.01"}
```

I want to print the `C08815303G7XXXXXX`, which is after `Serial Number"="` and before `"`. This part of the line isn't always in the same place but is always after `Serial Number"="` and before `"`.

Comment: `sed 's/^.*"Serial Number"="\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/.*Serial Number\"=\"|\".*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: @MelvinCornelissen, glad that it helped you, give it sometime and when you see enough answers on this post then you could select anyone of them as correct answer too, happy learning.